# Secure uploaded files in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have site based on Wordpress. Only logged user can see posts, sites, and files (I use s2member plugin).

I have problem with disabling access to files for unlogged user.

I upload files, attach it to post. Only logged user can see post and attachements.

The problem is that unlogged user can download files directly (e.g. http://my-site.pl/files/secret_file.pdf).

How can I prevent this, some plugin, .htaccess?

My site is on shared hosting i have access only via ftp.

Comment: Shared hosting will make that more difficult. Do you have access to a folder that's above the web root? (ie a folder not accessible via the web, but accessible to the server)

Comment: No... :(
I put files directly to www folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are potential solutions, but none stands out in practice -- each has its own set of thorns.

There are commercial plugins that implement access restriction on part or all of your WP site. Some allow to restrict files, some don't. Amember is one of the more established players in that arena. (I cannot recommend their offer, however. Amongst other problems I ran into, it didn't play well on a multi-server setup.) There probably are some free plugins that do the same since I last checked.

If you decide to code something yourself, there are multitudes of options. Three of them include:

1. Serving the file using php instead of Apache, and requiring the user to be logged in before serving the file. It works. And it's relatively easy to set up if you decide to be sloppy. It's not so easy if you want to set it up correctly: think partial files that need to be resumed, etc.
2. Conditionally serving the file using Apache. In essence, you create a user-specific file in a token folder, and you store the name of that file as a cookie when the user log in. Then, have Apache rewrite rules deny access if the corresponding file isn't present in the token folder. This is not easy to set up
3. Not restricting files at all and leaving things the way they are at the moment: a link to a publicly available file that only members can see. The rational here is that no matter how well you restrict access to your pdf, it'll end up on a torrent site or a download site somewhere if a disgruntled user decides to share it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in **.htacces**.  this allow user to download or view only  **.gif, .jpg,.jpeg,.png and .bmp** files.
if you don't want to allow this then remove the line **"Allow from env=let_me_in"**
I hope this will work.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# If the URI is an image then we allow accesses
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)$" let_me_in

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
# Allow accesses only if an images was requested
Allow from env=let_me_in
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```